# Missing context for svg in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

My webpack config

```
module:{
    rules:[{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ],
    }, { 
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
    }]
}
```

And I had this error.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/url-loader/index.js):
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined
>       at Object.loader
>
> (G:\SCM-New\pms-front-end-new\node_modules\file-loader\dist\index.js:34:49)
>       at Object.module.exports (G:\SCM-New\pms-front-end-new\node_modules\url-loader\index.js:37:25)
>    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) 7:4746-4798

I even try `file-loader` instead of `url-loader` but this will get even more error like above for `eot|ttf|woff|woff2`.

Config as follows

`{test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader'}`

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, can you help me out @bbqchickenrobot

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't resolve it either.  Some people had success with upgrading the WebPack library to 4.14.  I rolled back to the default version that is installed by  asp.net cli templates and that got around it.